# Xcode 7 fails to open with "Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore" message

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7

Xcode 7 fails to open on my Mac running OS X 10.10.5. A dialog box opens saying "Loading a plug-in failed". Starting Xcode from the command line outputs the following:

> 2015-09-20 23:39:36.616 Xcode[1511:58710] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading:
>   Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin),
>   error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle
>   “IDEiOSSupportCore” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or
>   missing necessary resources."
>   (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice

Answer (score 72):

Run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` and it configures your env.

Comment: Thanks for this, @oli-vettel! I was getting this error output to terminal with each new session.  Output from this command should be: 1%.........20.........40.........60.........80.........Install Succeeded then error  goes away.

Comment: @oli Thank a lot. This helped. Could you explain what was happening before the error?

Comment: I was having the same problems when trying to start UE5. I would get to 0% on the initializing and then this same error would pop up. I ran this and after a slow startup (MacOS reindexed the files, etc.) everything seems to be running as I expect. I'm with @PAULJOY that it would be nice to know what caused this but in my opinion this should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Got into kind of similar error I think

```
xcodebuild[3855:37375] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability
```

Re-install Xcode solved the issue.

Comment: worked for me, but I also had to launch Xcode once after re-installing (which then prompted it to install some MacOS and IOS components.) w/o this step I had the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

in my case, reinstalling Xcode solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling iTunes fixed this problem. [Download the latest iTunes version](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/), install it, and Xcode should open as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure x-code is fully installed then open to confirm ( you dont have to create a project)
you may or may not need to restart you machine, but just do it